# trigger input type color

Tags: javascript, jquery

При загрузкe страницы в `input type="color"` есть `value`, которое содержит уже по умолчанию цвет `#0000ff` - пробую сделать через `trigger("input")`, но ничего не происходит:

```
<input id="csmenu-1" value="#ff0080" class="js-csmenu-1" type="color">

$(".js-csmenu-1").trigger("input");
$(".js-csmenu-1").on("input", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(".js-view-csmenu").css("backgroundColor", val);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте последовательность назначения обработчика события `input` и вызов этого события.

```js
$(".js-csmenu-1").on("input", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(".js-view-csmenu").css("backgroundColor", val);
});
$(".js-csmenu-1").trigger("input");
```

```css
.js-view-csmenu
{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="csmenu-1" value="#ff0080" class="js-csmenu-1" type="color">
<div class="js-view-csmenu"><div>
```